# Set and Notation

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have a pretty simple question that only involves set and some notations. Define $f(x) = \frac{x^3}{x}$. Also define $A = \{ f(x) | x ∈ \{-1, 0, 1, 2\} \}$. Is $A = \{1, 4\}$? My main concerns are the repeated elements and undefined image of f.

Comment: I would say that $A$ is not defined since $f(0)$ is undefined. Repeated elements are fine, e.g. $f(1)=f(-1)=1$ and this element would only appear once in the set.

Comment: So if A = { f(x) | x ∈ {-1, 1, 2} }, then A is defined and is equaled to the set {1, 4}?

Comment: Your comment is correct @Kaiphomy

Comment: Thanks Dave and Kendall!

Answer (score 2):

In general, when we have sets, they contain at most one copy of any given element. In this case, since $f(-1) = f(1) = 1$, both "copies" of $1$ get collapsed into a single element. In this case however, because $f(0)$ is undefined, it's ambiguous whether $A$ is well-defined. I think leaving it undefined is generally more helpful as it ensures there are no ambiguities, but I've seen books where cases like this are just ignored.